# Rambam in the Original Judeo Arabic

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, rambam, books-generally, arabic

Any one know where I can find any of Rambam's works in the original Judeo-Arabic (preferably online and not a manuscript but an easily readable text)?

Comment: check this out: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/4277/moreh-nevuchim-arabic-hebrew

Comment: partial overlap: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73043

Comment: partial overlap: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73044

Answer (score 7):

Mekitzei Nirdamim published three volumes of the Rambam's responsa with facing columns of Judeo-Arabic and Hebrew (Jerusalem, 1958-1961). These are available on Hebrewbooks ([vol. 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/1730), [vol. 2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/1731), [vol. 3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/1732)).

Answer (score 3):

Here are the three volumes of Salomon Munk's edition of the Judeo-Arabic original of the *Guide of the Perplexed* (together with Munk's French translation), available free in full text on Google Books (the Arabic starts from the end of each volume):

- [Guide of the Perplexed: Munk ed. 1st vol.](http://books.google.com/books?id=8OQUAAAAQAAJ)
- [Guide of the Perplexed: Munk ed. 2nd vol.](http://books.google.com/books?id=GZk1AAAAIAAJ)
- [Guide of the Perplexed: Munk ed. 3rd vol.](http://books.google.com/books?id=zKc1AAAAIAAJ)

Here is Israel Efros's edition of the Judeo-Arabic text of the *Treatise on Logic* ascribed to Maimonides (together with three different Medieval translations into Hebrew), available on HebrewBooks:

- [Treatise on Logic: Efros ed.](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/39019)

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of the Kapach-translation of perush hamishnayot (published by Mosad Harav Kook) have the original arabic on one side. There's also a two volume set called "[Igrot HaRMBM](http://www.kotar.co.il/KotarApp/Viewer.aspx?nBookID=94129274#69.3619.5.fitwidth)" (its off-white in color) which has the original Arabic of all the correspondences printed before the translation.

Answer (score 1):

Goto [Sefarim Online.org](http://www.seforimonline.org/seforimdb/index.php?table_name=seforim_database&function=details&where_field=id&where_value=217).  I downloaded the Arabic manuscript from the site and it's pretty clear from what I remember.

The Kapach (Qafih) editions are nearly impossible to find and if you do, they're prohibitively expensive.

Answer (score 1):

It's not what people usually have in mind when they mention the Rambam's literature, but you can find the complete collection of his medical writings [here](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/series/BYU-MWMM.html), in the original Arabic and with English translation. Given that they are not usually thought of as "Torah", I'm not certain that it qualifies for this site, but they *were* authored by the Rambam and are significant by virtue of the fact.